# UCanAccess driver not in DriverManager.getDrivers() list unless Class.forName() is called

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

After reading about UCanAccess in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21955256/manipulating-an-access-database-from-java-without-odbc) I've started building it into my app. It seems to be working, but I've noticed an oddity.

I put in the following code at start-up, and found that it doesn't print anything, *unless* I preface it with a `Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver")` or other reference to the class. As long as I include that line, it will print out "driver found :..." as expected.

```
Enumeration<Driver> x = DriverManager.getDrivers();
while (x.hasMoreElements()) {
    Driver driver = x.nextElement();
    if (driver instanceof UcanaccessDriver) {
        System.out.println("driver found: " + driver.toString());
    }
}
```

However, I've seen it in comments on other UCanAccess questions that the `Class.forName()` shouldn't be needed before regular calls to `DriverManager.getDriver()` or whatever else. Is there a step I've missed?

Comment: In general a Driver class instance is seldom useful (almost never) for the applicative code so I'm wondering where you read something about DriverManager.getDriver() and Ucanaccess. I can't reproduce your example. What's your java version? Can you get the connection if you comment if( driver instanceof UcanaccessDriver block){...}(which has the same effect than a class.forName)

Comment: I am also unable to recreate your issue. I tried your code under Java 7 (JRE 1.7.0_67) and Java 8 (JRE 1.8.0_45) and they both listed the UCanAccess driver without having first done a `Class.forName()`.

Comment: My JDK version is 1.7.0_80, my UcanAccess version is 2.0.2-1. It's a reproducible error within my project, so I suppose if you guys can't get it to happen then it's probably something to do with our infrastructure. There are a few classloaders floating around the system, so perhaps it's a matter of the jar being on the wrong one until I explicitly call for it. Thank you for at least doing a preliminary investigation, anyway.

Comment: Oh, and the driver was only being used to do `connect()` the way the driver manager does. Since things were behaving strangely I was trying to do a little debugging by bringing more of the steps into my code where I can intersperse printlns and such.

Comment: Maybe you need to call the `getDrivers()` twice as described in this comment: https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/35b2d79ad26535deedcc0c6bea2a057138e1bd30/java/org/apache/catalina/loader/JdbcLeakPrevention.java#L47-L55